# Manipulação de ArrayList

Tags: java

Bom dia Amigos, estou com muita dificuldades em fazer essa aplicação funcionar, não estou conseguindo calcular os dias de faltas dos alunos, minha dificuldade está na classe Pauta no método marcarFalta(int getMatricula, int mes, int dia), pois tenho que pegar a matricula do aluno e dos dia da falta no referido mês.
Desde já agradeço.

```
package Gerenciar_frequencia;
public class Principal {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Turma turma = new Turma("Est. de dados","A1","20191");
    turma.inserirAluno(new Aluno("Anselmo",111));
    turma.inserirAluno(new Aluno("Pedro",222));
    turma.inserirAluno(new Aluno("Joao",333));
    turma.imprimir();
    System.out.println("------------------------------------------");
    Pauta pauta = new Pauta(3,6,turma);
    pauta.marcarFalta(111, 3, 5);
    pauta.marcarFalta(111, 3, 12);
    pauta.marcarFalta(111, 3, 21);
    pauta.marcarFalta(111, 3, 26);
    pauta.marcarFalta(111, 4, 2);
    pauta.marcarFalta(111, 4, 4);
    pauta.marcarFalta(111, 4, 11);
    pauta.marcarFalta(111, 4, 23);
    pauta.marcarFalta(111, 4, 25);
    pauta.marcarFalta(111, 4, 30);
    pauta.marcarFalta(111, 5, 7);
    pauta.marcarFalta(111, 5, 23);
    pauta.marcarFalta(222, 3, 12);
    pauta.marcarFalta(222, 3, 21);
    pauta.marcarFalta(222, 4, 9);
    pauta.marcarFalta(222, 4, 16);
    pauta.marcarFalta(222, 4, 25);
    pauta.marcarFalta(222, 4, 30);
    pauta.imprimir();

public class Turma {
    static String nomeTurma;
    String codigo;
    String periodo;
    ArrayList<Aluno> alunos = new ArrayList<>();
    public Turma(String nomeTurma, String codigo, String periodo) {
        this.nomeTurma = nomeTurma;
        this.codigo = codigo;
        this.periodo = periodo;
    }
    public void inserirAluno(Aluno a) {
        alunos.add(a);
    }
    public static String getNomeTurma() {
        return nomeTurma;
    }
    public void imprimir() {
        for (Aluno b: alunos) { 
            System.out.println(b);
        }
    }
 }
 public class Aluno {
    String nome;
    int matricula;
    public Aluno(String nome, int matricula) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.matricula = matricula;
    }
    public String toString(){
       return "Nome: " + this.nome + ", Matricula: " + this.matricula;
    }
    public int getMatricula() {
       return matricula;
    }
}
public class Pauta {
    int mesInicial;
    int mesFinal;
    public Pauta(int mesInicial, int mesFinal, Turma turma) {
        this.mesInicial = mesInicial;
        this.mesFinal = mesFinal;
    }
    public void marcarFalta(int getMatricula, int mes, int dia) {
        int i=0;
      for (Aluno falta : alunos){
          if (falta.getMatricula==getMatricula && falta.dia==dia){
              i++;
          }
      }
      return i;
    }
    public void imprimir() {
        System.out.println("Mês inicial: "+this.mesInicial+ ",Mês Final: "+ this.mesFinal+",Turma: "+ Turma.getNomeTurma());

    }
}
```

A Saida seria;

```
 Matricula: 111,  faltas:12;

 Matricula: 222,  faltas:6;
```

Esse é o erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved 
compilation problems: alunos cannot be resolved to a variable getMatricula 
cannot be resolved or is not a field getMatricula cannot be resolved to a 
variable dia cannot be resolved or is not a field at 
Gerenciar_frequencia.Pauta.marcarFalta(Pauta.java:12) at 
Gerenciar_frequencia.Principal.main(Principal.java:11)
```

Comment: Qual é o problema que está ocorrendo? algum erro? ou a saída está incorreta?

Comment: Eu dei uma olhada no seu código, está com muitos erros.

Comment: Felipe L. Constante. Os erros que você encontrou estão todos relacionados com a classe Pauta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pois bem... Comentei o seu código para que lhe de um norte para corrigir o problema, pois é bastante básico. Espero que com isso eu consiga ajuda-lo.

```
public void marcarFalta(int getMatricula, int mes, int dia) {
        int i=0;
      for (Aluno falta : alunos){ // De onde vem o "alunos"?
          if (falta.getMatricula() == getMatricula && falta.dia == dia){ //O falta.da não existe, de onde ele vem?
              i++;
          }
      }
      return i; // Porque você está retornando o inteiro i, se sua classe é void?
    }

public void imprimir() {
            System.out.println("Mês inicial: " + this.mesInicial + ",Mês Final: " + this.mesFinal + ",Turma: "
                    + Turma.getNomeTurma()); //Você precisa instanciar esse cara.

        }
```

Outra coisa, se você estiver usando classes internas, você precisa deixa-las estáticas. Aconselho que você dê uma boa pesquisada sobre java básico e programação orientada a objetos.

Corrija isso e seu código irá compilar

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Felipe L. Constante, obrigado amigo pelas observações, irei trabalhar em cima delas.

Comment: Se houver dúvidas, não deixe de perguntar.. Tem uma comunidade inteira disposta a ajudar.. :)

Answer (score 1):

O erro pode estar ocorrendo pelo erro na declaração da variável **getMatricula** recebida por parâmetro:

Erro: `if (falta.getMatricula==getMmatricula && falta.dia==dia)`

Correção: `if (falta.getMatricula() == getMatricula && falta.dia == dia)`

Comment: Olá. isto não é uma resposta e sim um comentário, existe a opção de inserir um comentário na pergunta.

Comment: Certo, mas infelizmente não tenho o privilégio de comentar em um post ainda. Poderia explicar melhor sobre o problema?

Comment: Recomendo a [leitura](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5509/77268)

Comment: Caio, passei por este mesmo problema. E eu entendo a preocupação da comunidade em relação a isso e eles estão corretos. Por mais que tenhamos boas intensões, há muitos que não tem e acabam poluindo. Então, se me permitir lhe dar ma sugestão: aguarde que o pessoal da comunidade vai questionar, até que você tenha os pontos necessários para conseguir comentar.. e não é tão longe.. :)

Comment: Olá amigos, não consigo compilar esse código, está dando erro na linha marcarFalta da classe Pauta,  não coloquei para imprimir ainda as faltas só estou com dificuldade em pegar a matricula e o dia da falta e ir contabilizando.

Comment: Qual é o erro? Coloque o erro que está dando.

Comment: Caio menezes. Corrigi o getMatricula , mas continua o erro, obrigado amigo pela orientação.

Comment: esse é o erro:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 alunos cannot be resolved to a variable
 getMatricula cannot be resolved or is not a field
 getMatricula cannot be resolved to a variable
 dia cannot be resolved or is not a field

 at Gerenciar_frequencia.Pauta.marcarFalta(Pauta.java:12)
 at Gerenciar_frequencia.Principal.main(Principal.java:11)